# How to align the children fieldset inside the parent fieldset?

Tags: html, css

I want to align two fieldset offer & Demand inside the parent fieldset type. How to do for a simple case provided below? It includes both html & css.
I am using um-ordered list inside the parent fieldset. But the alignment does not work. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
<title>Align Fieldset</title>
<style>
.header{
    width: 100%;
    clear:both;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: medium;
    float:left;
}
.subheader{
    width: 100%;
    clear:both;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: medium;
    float:left;
}
.list{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<p>Aligning offer & Demand on the same line</p>
<fieldset  class="header">

<legend>Type</legend>
<ul class= "list">
 <li>
 <fieldset class="subheader">   
  <legend ><label> 
  <input type="radio" name="Type" value="Offer" checked="checked"
  />Offer</label>
  </legend>
 </fieldset>  
  </li>   
  <li>
  <fieldset class="subheader">   
      <legend><label> 
           <input type="radio" name="Type" value="Demand">Demand</label>
      </legend> 
  </fieldset>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </fieldset> <!-- End of type -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have wrapped your fieldsets into a list, you should focus your attention to the `ul` and `li`. I cleaned out all of the extraneous styles. [**`display: flex`**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is what made this layout problem a cakewalk. The following is the relevant CSS that was changed:

```
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.list li {
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Align Fieldset</title>
  <style>
    .header {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .subheader {
      width: 100%;
      font-size: medium;
    }
    .list {
      list-style-type: none;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }
    .list li {
      margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Aligning offer & Demand on the same line</p>
  <fieldset class="header">

    <legend>Type</legend>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>
        <fieldset class="subheader">
          <legend>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="Type" value="Offer" checked="checked" />Offer</label>
          </legend>
        </fieldset>
      </li>
      <li>
        <fieldset class="subheader">
          <legend>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="Type" value="Demand">Demand</label>
          </legend>
        </fieldset>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
  <!-- End of type -->
</body>

</html>
```

Not related to the question: I changed your `meta` to `utf-8`.

Comment: It does not work in Adobe Dreamweaver CS6. May be it does not understand "display: flex;"

Comment: @MansourGHAFFARZADEH I use DWCS6 myself but it doesn't matter what editor you use, it depends on the browser the user will use. It will work in Firefox, Chrome, IE 10+,  and Safari . http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @MansourGHAFFARZADEH Best way to test with DWCS6 is with the test in browser feature. On the toolbar if you see a globe icon, use that instead. If you rely too much on the the design mode, you'll never get an accurate rendering. Adobe has abandoned DWCS6 so it won't get any more updates.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<style>
.header{
width: 100%;
clear:both;
display: inline-block;
font-size: medium;
float:left;
}
.subheader{
/* change */
width: auto;
clear:both;
display: inline-block;
font-size: medium;
float:left;
}
.list{
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
width: auto;
float: left;
 }
/* add */
li{
  float:left;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a specific width to ".list"(ex:100%) and specific with to ".subheader" elements(remove clear:both from it).
Try to not use display:inline-block and float at same time.